# Is it safe to modify the texture used by opengl?

Tags: opengl, cuda

I have an application which uses Ogre engine for rendering (OpenGL). There's a texture that binded to the pipeline. Also there's a CUDA call that modifies that texture. Basically it looks like this:

```
cudaGraphicsMapResources(tex);

// call cuda kernel that writes to te texture

cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(tex);
```

How safe is this? Is it possible that CUDA will update the texture that is currently in use by OpenGL? I don't know OpenGL but know other APIs. In DirextX 12 or vulkan I need to set barriers or other sync mechanisms for this kind of work. But on the other hand DirectX 11 allows to update mapped resources safely because it has synchronization inside the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be safe to do this, primarily because OpenGL stores all relevant buffers and IDs in the GPU. Note however, you might not be able to update the texture that is bound to the GPU.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the stuff works, but I want to be sure there's no undefined behavior. Can you please provide a link to the documentation or other resource that explain this guarantee?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the texture is mapped to CUDA resource, any attempt to read or write on OpenGL side will lead to undefined results.It is explicitly stated in [CUDA docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__INTEROP.html#group__CUDART__INTEROP_1gad8fbe74d02adefb8e7efb4971ee6322).

Comment: Yes, I saw this paragraph - `The graphics API from which resources were registered should not access any resources while they are mapped by CUDA.`. But what does it mean - accessing a resource by the API. Between mapping and unmapping I'm not calling any OpenGL.

Comment: The CUDA kernel doesn't run in sync with OpenGL pipeline. Also, it's possible that CUDA or GL run in separate thread. That means, one can potentially access the texture from GL side while it's still mapped to CUDA context. Don't do that.

Comment: On the other hand the same documentation you referenced says that `the function provides the synchronization guarantee that any graphics calls issued before cudaGraphicsMapResources() will complete before any subsequent CUDA work issued in stream begins.` It sounds like CUDA have a synchronization with OpenGL.